# Getting "builder", "parent_builder", and "namespace" fields returned from Postgresql/Hstore in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I built a simple application, which i am trying to update with a form, but got some weirdness going on.

I have a column 'field_items' which is an hStore. If i call debug on the model in my view...

```
<%= debug @app.field_items %>
```

I get the two proper items returned. In the rails console i also do not see the three extras.

I have a form_for where i iterate over the 'field_items'

In my form it returns three extra fields "builder", "parent_builder", and "namespace"

Anyone have any ideas? I have noticed if i comment out the serialize line on :field_items in the model, it doesn't return the three extra attributes

---

Here is my model

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :layouts, :field_items

  serialize :layouts, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
  serialize :field_items, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore  
end
```

Here is the form/code from my edit view

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @app], :html => { :class => "form app_fields_form" } do |f| -%>
    <div id="app_fields_row_container">
        <%= f.fields_for :field_items, @app.field_items do |fi| %>
            <% @app.field_items.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
                <div class='app_fields_row item_row'>
                    <div class="column col1"><%= text_field_tag key, key, :class => "form_text_field dynamic_attr" %></div>
                    <div class="column col2"><%= fi.select key, options_for_select(APP_FIELD_TYPES, value), {}, {:class => "form_select"} %></div>
                    <div class="column col3"><a href="#" class="adm_button h_red small grey app_fields_delete">x</a></div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <%- end -%>
    </div>  
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Did you figure out why you got those attributes? I have the same problem.

Comment: I got it to work removing the corresponding argument to your @app.field_items.

Comment: @graphmeter can you post what you changed exactly as an answer? I'll accept it if its the fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Removing @app.field_items from fields_for worked for me

```
<%= f.fields_for :field_items do |fi| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line and it should work fine:

```
<%= f.fields_for :field_items, @app.field_items do |fi| %>
```

I had the exact same problem, and removing the `fields_for` call solved the issue, as there is no need for it as it isn't a nested resource.